# Request method mapping is happening after permission check

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

I have a view that creates and updates user as shown below.

```
class UserViewSet(ViewSet):
    def check_permissions(self, request):
        print("Action = ", self.action)
        if self.action == 'create_user':
            return True
        return super().check_permissions(request)

    def create_user(self, request):
        # user creation code

    def update(self, request):    
        #user update code
```

And `create_user` is mapped with *POST* method and `update` is mapped with *PUT* method. So, `create_user` action should not require authenticated user but for update, user should be authenticated. Overriding `check_permission` did the job. Now, when I was testing the create_user end point. I wrote a test that tries to creates user using some method other than *POST*. I expected that the response should be `HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED`.

```
def test_create_user_with_invalid_method(self):
    data = self.user_data
    response = self.client.put(self.url, data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

But the response was `HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED`. And the action variable was set as `None`. My url mapping is like this:

```
url(r'^account/register/$', UserViewSet.as_view({"post": "create_user"}),name="account_register_view"),
url(r'^account/update/$', UserViewSet.as_view({"put": "update"}), name="account_update_vew"),
```

So looking at this, I thought djago is either doing the mapping of request(method, url) to action either after checking permission or doing it before but setting action as None when it fails to find the proper mapping

So my concern is that whether this is the correct behaviour and the test i wrote and what i was expecting is wrong or is there something strange going on here.